# Can faceted counts be accessed by the stat()-function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

As in the title. I know I can calculate in-group percentages by calculating them prior to plotting, so if I write:

```
fulldata %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
  summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
  mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))%>% 
  ggplot(.) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

I can get something like this:

[image]

But would I be able to get the same results using some combination of stat() and count()-functions? Are the calculated aesthetics *of the actual facets* available for manipulation?

Could we write something along the lines of:

```
ggplot(fulldata, aes(x=gymnasiegrov)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=stat.facet(count) / stat(count))) +
  facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

And get the same results?

Small excerpt:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 
9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), totstatus_tri = c("pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Large excerpt

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 
    8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 
    3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 
    7L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
    9L, 8L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
    7L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 
    9L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 7L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
    7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
    "Hotell- och Restaurang", "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
    "naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
    "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
    "estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), totstatus_tri = c("pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "troligt avbrott", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
    "troligt avbrott", "pågående studier", "pågående studier"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -154L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:154)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: use `dput(YOURDATA)` or if that's too long `dput(head(YOURDATA))` so that we can recreate your question.

Comment: I though fo this of a general question (e.g "are these variables available?") but i''ve uploaded a small and large excerpte of my data.

Comment: If you have specific ways you want to do a calculation to show in a plot, you're likely better off doing those calculations beforehand instead of relying on ggplot to be able to do them how you want